# Android: How to link state from button to state of textview in same layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I've developed a custom control for a button that can have an image and a text, as I didn't find a standard widget that can do that. It works nice, but what I run into now is, that when the button is clicked, the textview does not change it's state to pressed. I would like to have this behaviour so that I can apply a [ColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) for the textview, so that the text color changes when the button is pressed.
This is my xml layout of the custom button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image_text_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
    android:visibility="visible"

     >

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layoutContent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/testing_teaser1"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textField"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="This is a ImageTextButton"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_bg_selector"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

How can I link the textview to the button state? `android:duplicateParentState="true"` does not work, because the button is not the parent of the textview.

Cheers Dude

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just set the `OnClickListener` to the `LinearLayout` or `FrameLayout` instead of setting it to `Button`, in the `Button` xml, you should also add         `android:duplicateParentState="true"`

Comment: Very nice solution. Works like a charm! But had to set the Button to `android:clickable=false`, so that it not intercepts the click.

Answer (score 1):

You know that there is an widget that does exactly that? ( [`ImageButton`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) )

If you still want to go with your custom component, you should assign the "@drawable/btn_bg_selector" to your parent `FrameLayout` and make that layout `clickable` instead of the `Button`.

Comment: Can I set text to an ImageButton that appears below the image?

Answer (score -1):

In the xml for button add the attribute

```
android:onClick="clickAction"
```

and in the activity include the following function

```
public void clickAction(View view){
   //Code whatever you want when the button is clicked
}
```